# How to call model method anywhere inside project without controller call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-5

I have model tasks inside of method name is not_completed_list have some records stored in @list variable .i need to loop that variable (@list)from view without controller how is it?

### Task.rb

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
    def self.not_completed_list
      @list= Person.pluck(:completed_on)#[name1,name2,name3]
    end
end
```

### My view

```
not_completed_list.@list do |x|
  puts x#1sttime looping name1,2nd time..name2,3rd time name3
end
```

Comment: What is `not_completed_list`? Is it an instance of `Task`?

Comment: `Task.not_completed_list.each do |x| ...`

Comment: `not_completed_list.@list do |x|` ? applying block on what ? calling class method on what, helper ?

Comment: Unless i'm missing something you many wanted to fetch users for which task is not completed?

Answer (score 2):

Just do following in view,

```
<% Task.not_completed_list.each do |completed_on| %>
```

And model should be,

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  def self.not_completed_list
    Person.pluck(:completed_on)
  end
end
```

but your implementation and flow need lots of changes.

You could get it your view simply without creating any class method,

```
<% Person.pluck(:completed_on).each do |completed_on| %>
```

Comment: In this case, isn't `Task.not_completed_on` functionally an alias for `Person.pluck(:completed_on)`?

Comment: @jvillian I updated, actually there is no role of `Task` model to do with it, and as per her case, no class method is needed.